# Chaining multiple Spring Batch readers?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and I'm writing an API bridge that will run in an independent Spring Boot application. Every hour, it will query a REST endpoint for information and push it out to a third party app via a POST to a NetSuite form.

However I'm not to sure how to structure this in terms of Readers, Processors and/or Writers.

The read involves multiple REST calls :

1. First I GET a series of USER ids (providing a filter)
2. For each id, I GET the corresponding USER along with a list of associated ITEMs.
3. I then iterate through the list of ITEMs and, based on a timestamp, chose to include this ITEM or not.
4. For each chosen ITEMs, I GET a SUMMARY (a PDF generated by the
   endpoint)

The data to send on to the NetSuite form is the SUMMARY PDF and the properties of the associated USER. I'm not currently at liberty to make changes to the REST API.

'Writing' out to NetSuite is pretty straight-forward but should I perform all of the above read steps within the same reader or is there some kind of built-in chaining that could be used ? So far I have steps 1 & 2 coded within a single reader.

Cheers,

AW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). For example in your case:

- The reader performs the first GET request and returns the list of IDs.
- For each item (ID), a processor performs other REST calls to gather user details (enrich the item) and any necessary information to be written
- The writer performs the POST request

For the processor, you can do all REST calls in the same processor or split them in separate processors and chain them with a `CompositeItemProcessor`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It does, I'll get onto it! I just wonder if Spring Batch is overkill for this rather than just using a @Scheduled job...